# Using ADB with Android Studio and Cordova

Tags: cordova, android-studio

I'm trying to use ADB to debug a Cordova application. When I navigated to my Cordova app folder in the command line and typed 'abd logcat -v long' I got the error message 'adb is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'. I have Android Studio installed on my computer but there are no ADB files within it (only 'stat_sys_adb.xml'). I don't have SDK tools on my computer. Just wondering how I can use ADB to get an error log for my app? [I've attached the file structure within my Android Studio folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzKs6.png)

Comment: Copy the `adb` binary to a folder that is defined within your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By the binary do you mean an ADB folder (I don't have one in the Android Studio folder)?